# Getting GPS position with libgdx

Tags: android, gps, libgdx

i wanted to get the gps position of an user while playing a game (libgdx). I found [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) tutorial for creating an GPSTracker for android phones. my problem is, that this is written for Android Activities/Tasks, but not for libgdx. without libgdx it works perfectly, but i don't know how to use it with libgdx and [there isn't any opportunity](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1832) for using gps with libgdx, yet.

does somebody know if it's possible to use GPS through libgdx and how? it would be very nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to create your `GPSTracker` from the Android project wrapper and pass it to the `Game` instance.

This is what I did to test.-

```
GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
MyGame game = new MyGame(gps.getLatitude(),  gps.getLongitude());
```

`GPSTracker` is returning well my current coordinates.

Comment: i tried this, but my problem was, that the `GPSTracker` class needs a value of the type `Context`. in the android project, i committed `MainActivity.this`, but when using libgdx, the contentView isn't on MainActivity...

Comment: Mmh just tried and it seems it's working and returning right coordinates (I'm editing my answer). Are you getting any exception maybe?

Comment: of course, that would work but i want to initialize the GPSTracker in a deep subclass of the game. of course, i could commit it to every subclass, but then it would be saved in each of these. isn't there a better option?

Comment: For those situations, I usually have a `singleton class`, like `MyGameUtils`. You could have one to store the GPSTracker instance, that way any class in your game should have access to it.

Comment: i tried this, but i think there must be an error: http://pastebin.com/K8vWUi32 when i test it on my phone, the app crashs.

Comment: ok sorry, it works with the singleton class, but only when gps is enabled. when it's not, there isn't a message to turn it on (but it should) and it crashs..

Comment: Mmh... what about leaving `GPSTracker` instance in your `MainActivity`, and creating a basic class (i.e. `GPSInfo`) with the fields of interest (such as `latitude` and `longitude`). You would pass an instance of this new class instead of `GPSTracker`'s, and keep its reference also in your Main, which you could update inside the callback methods of `GPSTracker`.

Comment: i think the problem is, that the Dialog can't be called. Maybe it's because the ContentView is on the libgdx Activity and not on the MainActivity anymore?

Comment: i think i have solved it: i get the view of libgdx with `initializeForView()` in the MainActivity, see this: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/NativeUIConfirmDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can get context object from Applicaion object(look this: [Static way to get 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android)) , then use the connect to construct the GPSTracker class.

Comment: there is one problem: the MainActivity Class is in the android project, so i can't call `MainActivity.getAppContext()` from any other class (in my case it's the renderer class).

Comment: Yes. So you can get context from a static methon from Application Class, The Application object will be maintain when any component of you app is running.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the context to the GPSTracker, try it in your AndroidLauncher.java in the onCreate Method with "getApplicationContext()"

```
AndroidLauncher.context = getApplicationContext();
this.gps = new GPSTracker(this.context);

AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(gps.getLatitude(),  gps.getLongitude()), config);
```